# Gitlab repository time length and size of of file storage

Tags: gitlab

I am not sure this is the right forum for this question.

I use Gitlab for storing all my codes, version control, etc. since I don' trust my PC. It suddenly dawned on me, will my account get deleted if I don't access it for a while or is there a limit to size of project that I can push there, etc. Basically use Gitlab for file storage also.

I didn't find any relevant answers on google. Can you please point me to these answers?

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab has a maximum auf 10G/repo. If you have larger files you should use Git LFS otherwise git is for small code files. So i don't think that your account is deleted if you are inactive. Otherwise you should get an e-mail with a notification.

https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2015/04/08/gitlab-dot-com-storage-limit-raised-to-10gb-per-repo/

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/lfs/manage_large_binaries_with_git_lfs.html